# Sections are labeled as 0.x in the output

Tags: sectioning, numbering, report

This is probably a very basic question, but I am new at this. I am using `\section{}` to create a new section. Latex labels it as 0.1. How can I get it to label it as 1.0?

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're using `report` that wants chapters; probably you need `article`, instead.

Comment: Switching back to `report` worked. I also understand how the second option works. Thanks.